# Typescript - How to direct all transpiled js/map files to the build directory

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular2/Typescript project, and it has the following tsconfig.js file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "./build"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
    "typings"
    ],
    "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

See... I am trying to "get rid" of the annoying *.js and *.map files that are generated next to my typescript files. You can see I added a "outDir" configuration, but it only copies the js/map files to the build folder, leaving a copy of the *.js files in the same folder as the ts.

Is there a missing configuration here?

Ionic2 has this "feature" built in. TS files are automatically transpiled onto the build folder (and packed...). Can this be achieved with "vanialla" tyepscript environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio Code, you can add the following to the settings.json, and this will keep those file from showing in the file/folder view.

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/*.js": true,
        "**/*.map": true
    }
}
```

You didn't mention the IDE you're using, so I am making an assumption. This may work with other IDEs, I don't really know.

Comment: Hey that's not an answer to my question, but it IS an answer for me, since I am using VSC! Big thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I don't know of a way to rid yourself of those files (delete them), but out of sight, out of mind, right? :)

Comment: Although it might be a problem if one of the js files is needed... I won't even know it's there... so, it needs a solution to the root problem...